# CKEditor: input elements not displaying in proper order

Tags: dialog, ckeditor

Whenever I click on the CKEditor dialog (eg: add image, hyperlink etc) form elements are not displaying in proper format. Guide me that how Can I resolve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are interfering with CKEditor styling. You need to open developer tools and check which of your selectors are applied to CKEditor elements and fix those selectors to be more precise.

Comment: i didnt applied any style, this is just a demo page, means just jquery file and ckeditor file is included, nothing else :(

Comment: Ok, nonstandard skin confused me - I thought that it's some system under the dialog. There are two options then. Either this skin is buggy, or your browser is not supported. Note that when testing on IE in intranet it runs in compatibility mode and this skin may not support it.